# Unplugging external monitor forces me to reboot

Tags: multi-monitor, laptop

I use a script that runs `xrandr` to turn off laptop display, showing only the external monitor screen.

I have another script that basically "reverses" this (showing only laptop display) which I use every time I have to take my laptop to a coffee shop.

Sometimes, in a hurry, I don't do this and just unplug my laptop directly before putting it in the bag. Now when I reach the coffee shop and try to use it, I would only see a blank screen which is due to what I assume to be my video configuration still being in "external screen only" mode. **Question**: how do I go to "laptop screen only" mode here? Otherwise, is there a way I can avoid having this problem in the first place?

Without knowing this I simply force reboot my laptop, which sucks.

For the record I run NixOS on Thinkpad P71.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383558/52236) suggests, no event is fired on a monitor connect/disconnect event. If it is really so, then it is a major bottleneck of the Linux/X11 GUI in my opinion.

That answer suggests polling as a workaround (`xrandr --listmonitors` shows the connected / disconnected monitors, executing a script periodically would be a solution).

However, polling is bad. A better option would be to bind a monitor fixer script to a keyboard shortcut. Write a script, which

1. gets the a list of the connected/disconnected monitors
2. turns off always the one what you want (depending on, which is connected)
3. *bind its execution to a keyboard shortcut*.

Comment: Thanks. I think I might go with the polling approach. Keyboard shortcut probably won't work if I find myself in a lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

As an short term fix to avoid reboot, unlock your screen, hit the keyboard shortcut to open terminal, and run `xrandr --output eDP1 --auto` to turn on your monitor again. You can do all of that 'blind' while your monitor is disabled.