# Dynamic configuration of monitors (Debian, Intel i915)

Tags: debian, openbox, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I have an Asus EEE PC 701 laptop with 7" 800x480 screen running Debian Jessie with Openbox as a WM. As I try to maximally use all the capabilities of this laptop, I'm searching for a way to get a dynamically-configurable dual monitor setup, so that when I feel limited by this laptop's small screen, I can just attach an external monitor and it will work. However, there seems to be little or no information about it, keeping in mind that I have integrated **Intel** GPU with one VGA output. The question is - what should I install&&configure in order to just plug in a monitor in my laptop and instantly have my workspace extended?

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22462/39954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own script and use [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr).

examples: 
check if new monitor is connected:

```
xrandr | grep -i conntected
```

But you can grep your new monitor.

```
xrandr | grep -i "The name of your monitor"
```

So if the command:

xrandr | grep -i "the name of your monitor" is true do something with it.

```
if (xrandr | grep -i "connected"); then                                  
  echo "yes"
  # do something with the new monitor 
else
  # no new monitors connected do nothing
  echo "nope"
fi
```

Comment: Aha, so it all comes to polling =( In the end, I just installed arandr and forgot about anything being dynamic, that's all. Thank you for your answer!